# How to concatenate 3 resultset values together in jtextfield?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to concatenate 3 resultset values from my database and display them together in one textfield but its not working i am getting only last value that is "city" displayed in textbox.

```
PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement("select  bk_name as bank,bk_branch as branch,bk_add as city from bk_det WHERE rm_id = ?");
ResultSet rs2;
String rm2 = tf_rmid.getText().trim();
stmt2.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(rm2));
rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
while (rs2.next()) {
    tf_remby.setText(rs2.getString("bank"));
    tf_remby.setText(rs2.getString("branch"));
    tf_remby.setText(rs2.getString("city"));
}
```

I tried doing:

```
tf_remby.setText(rs2.getString("bank"+","+"branch"+","+"city"));
```

and also

```
tf_remby.setText(rs2.getString("bank"+"branch"+"city"));
```

but neither works. Does anyone have any suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your while loop, you could try something like:

```
String text = rs2.getString("bank") + ", " +
              rs2.getString("branch") + ", " +
              rs2.getString("city");
tf_remby.setText(text);
```

But if you have multiple values in the result set, you'll only see the last bank/branch/city record anyway.

Comment: This what is my problem man i want to get multiple values concatinated together

Comment: What I posted should concatenate the three fields together. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: ya its working man thnx can we just try to convert the text in capslock

Comment: Caps lock? Do you mean convert to uppercase? If so, look at `String.toUpperCase()`.